# How to Preload only few images in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am Building a BlogApp and I want my Image Page to load only few images after open the Image.

**What i am trying to do:-**

I am trying to `Load only 9 images in the Server`. I mean :- When user opens the Page then, load only few images that are in front of the page, and if user scrolls then load next few images.

**What is happening Now:-**

When i open the server now, It loads all the Images that are uploaded in the Page. AND i don't want to load all the Images in the Page.

**What have i tried:-**

- I also tried `Preload` function in `HTML` BUT it didn't worked for me.

  ```
    <img preload="auto">
        <src="{{ image.file.url }}" width="200">
    </img>
  ```

I don't know what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: I don't think preload is available for images, you want to check out `<img loading=lazy>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to lazily load images. You can set `loading="lazy"` to do that.

```
<img src="{{ image.file.url }}" width="200" loading="lazy">
```

This will cause the browser to wait until user scrolls near the image to load it.

Reference: [Lazy loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading)